# .htaccess redirection if file exist

Tags: .htaccess

I have a directory structure like this

```
/ub/
/ub/img/
/ub/inc/
```

Basically I want to change my `img` URL to it's parent directory `(ub)`,

When i access `http://localhost/ub/mypic.jpg`

First, it has to check `/ub/img/mypic.jpg`, if exist then get that file and pass to the browser, if not then just pass it to  `http://localhost/ub/index.php?img=mypic.jpg` with INTERNAL REDIRECTION.

Second, index.php will create `mypic.jpg` and store it to `/ub/img/`, then pass `mypic.jpg` to the browser.

So, whether the file is exist or not, the browser will only have `http://localhost/ub/mypic.jpg` as the URL

So far, i have this on my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/ub/img/$1 -f
RewriteRule .+ /ub/img/$1 [L]
```

I have 2 days to find out the solution, but, it doesn't seem to work,

Thanks,

**EDIT :**

Hey, I've got this, The request to `http://localhost/ub/app/file.php` is already passed to `index.php?uri=app/file.php` as i expected,

but the request to `http://localhost/ub/img/mypic.jpg` is not passed to `index.php?uri=img/mypic.jpg`. Is there any solution?

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ub/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([^/]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}ub/img/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ img/%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([^/]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}ub/inc/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ inc/%1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (place it in .htaccess in the /ub folder):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ub/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([^/]+\.jpg)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/ub/img/%1 -f
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?img=$1
```

Comment: Can you pinpoint where it's failing or what's not working? Syntax error? Wrong rewrite?

Comment: Check your server logs and see what the error is - it's hard to debug otherwise since the rule depends on existing files etc.

Comment: hey, I edit my question. Is there any solution? thanks before.

Comment: You should probably post a new question. Anyway, the reason it's not written is probably because /ub/img/mypic.jpg already exists. If it doesn't you need to provide more info about where you're placing the .htaccess file and whether ub and ub/img are real folders.

Comment: i am so sorry for that, /ub/img/mypic.jpg is a real folder, but i don't want the user to be able to get that URL, /ub/mypic.jpg instead. i put the .htaccess file in /ub/ directory, and ub/img is a real folder as the same as inc folder

Comment: If /ub/img is a real folder then the .htaccess file in /ub will not be processed.

Comment: btw, how to let it be processed? based on my edited question app is processed while app is also a real folder

Comment: My mistake, I believe it will be processed. Let me think about why it won't be in case of img. Can you add rewrite log rules?

Comment: The reason it's not being rewritten is because /ub/img/mypic.jpg exists, and in that case your rule says to rewrite it to /ub/img/mypic.jpg , and the [L] says it's the last rule to be executed.

Comment: when I go to `http://localhost/ub/img/mypic.jpg`

strip per-dir prefix: D:/ub/img/mypic.jpg -> img/mypic.jpg
applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'img/mypic.jpg'
RewriteCond: input='/ub/img/mypic.jpg' pattern='([^/]+)$' => matched
RewriteCond: input='D:/ub/img/mypic.jpg' pattern='-f' => matched
rewrite 'img/mypic.jpg' -> 'img/mypic.jpg'
add per-dir prefix: img/mypic.jpg -> D:/ub/img/mypic.jpg
initial URL equal rewritten URL: D:/ub/img/mypic.jpg [IGNORING REWRITE]

Comment: Yes like I said, the file exists, so it ignores the rewrite.

Comment: ok, then, if I don't want the user to have that URL (404 not found error generated by `index.php?uri=img/mypic.jpg` instead), how is the way?
I just change `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([^/]+)$` to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ub/([^/]+)$` in order request to /ub/img/mypic.jpg will be passed to `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]`, but it loops here